# how to configure data source in jetty on azure?

Tags: azure, jetty, azure-web-app-service

I'm considering using [azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) to host my java jetty web application. As most of webapps, my app requires a specific jdbc datasource to be configured on jetty and I don't know how to do this on azure.
I had a look at [Java with MySQL official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-java-mysql), but it's for a spring application, so the way described there does not apply to my app (my app requires datasource available in JNDI named "xxxxDS"). I tried to google it, but also no luck...

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Comment: Check this link and see if its of any help https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/run-java-with-jetty-in-windows-azure/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I figured that out: instead of putting my war file directly to `site/wwwroot/webapps` I put a jetty web app xml descriptor there instead. Inside this xml descriptor I can configure a datasource.

Now however I'm struggling with this to make it work: [how to add custom jars to GLOBAL jetty classpath on azure web app service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324531/how-to-add-custom-jars-to-global-jetty-classpath-on-azure-web-app-service)