# how to add custom jars to GLOBAL jetty classpath on azure web app service?

Tags: azure, jetty, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a java web app on jetty on [azure web app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) that uses postgres data source. The problem is that I don't know how to add postgres JDBC driver to global jetty classpath, which is required by jetty to create the data source before deploying my app (hence I can't just add the driver to `WEB-INF/lib` subfolder of my war).

I've tried to create `site/wwwroot/lib/ext` folder and put the driver there, but it seems that jetty's ext module which should automatically add all jars from this folder to the global classpath is not enabled.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please run `$ cd site/wwwroot && java -jar /path/to/jetty-home-ver/start.jar --list-config` and update your question with the results.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt unfortunately you can't run arbitrary commands on azure jetty web app service (at least to my knowledge/understanding), so I can't do it :(

Comment: ah, I think I found "console" tool on azure portal: let me try this :)